# Turtle control the rate of refresh using sleep does not refresh properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm controlling turtle animation by using tracer(0, 0) and stamping the turtle cursor itself.

However, it refreshes strangely, it's suppose to be 1 second between any animation (with sleep) but it seems to sometimes hang for two second, then a couple of second later zaps into position: [image]

The code is:

```
import turtle
import time

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.listen()
screen.tracer(0, 0)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.shape("circle")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()

next = [0, 8]

time.sleep(10)

while True:
    pen.goto(next[0]*20, next[1]*20)
    screen.clear()
    pen.stamp()
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    next = [next[0], next[1]-1]
```

Seems like simply sleeping is not a good idea. I seem to also have trouble getting it to work with threading. How do I it works with a predefined time like 1 second in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the efficiency of your computer, `time.sleep(1)` would have different durations.
Instead of relying on the efficiency of your computer to adjust the `sleep` duration, you can use the `perf_counter` method to detect how long your program has been running from one part to another.

Basically, once you run the program, the time tracking starts. Where ever you call `time.perf_counter()`, it will return the amount of time for the start of the program to reach the place you called `time.perf_counter()`.

```
import turtle
import time

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.listen()
screen.tracer(0, 0)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.shape("circle")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()

nxt = [0, 8]

time.sleep(10)

while True:
    start = time.perf_counter() # Find the total performance time from the start of the program to here
    pen.goto(nxt[0]*20, nxt[1]*20)
    screen.clear()
    pen.stamp()
    screen.update()
    while time.perf_counter() - start < 1: # Keep looping until the amount of performance time from right under "while True" to this line reaches 1 second
        pass
    nxt = [nxt[0], nxt[1]-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sleep` and `while True:` loops in an event-driven world like turtle is a bad idea.  We can instead use a timer event to produce the effect you describe.  While we're at it, we're going to toss *stamping* as that's not adding anything, and neither are `clear()` and `listen()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def drop():
    screen.update()
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - CURSOR_SIZE)

    screen.ontimer(drop, 1000)  # 1 second

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.penup()

turtle.sety(160)

screen.ontimer(drop, 10_000)  # 10 seconds

screen.mainloop()
```

Of course, you need to add some logic to avoid restarting the timer event if/when the circle falls off the bottom of the screen.  By using `while True:` loops, and `sleep()` you potentially block events, like user keystrokes or window closing, from reaching turtle.

One minor inaccuracy here is the `drop()` method takes some minimal time to run -- to factor that out, if needed/desired, you need to adjust the timing based on clock time or something like `time.perf_counter()` as @AnnZen demonstrates, but not in a `pass` loop!

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: Is there any other way that I can inject action into the loop? My example is a simplified example, but in reality I have to have a recursive function to be written by Python newbies as an exercise to find a way out of a maze also drawn with turtle. I definitely need the stamp for this reason as well.

Comment: clear() clears everything, map needs to be redrawn, the turtle need to be re-stamped. I want the map to be drawn instantaneously, and the circle to move through the maze (jumping from coordinate to coordinate much like the animation I have shown, no need to be smooth). So every time I want the stamped circle to move, I need to redraw the whole canvas. But since drawing is slow, I don't want it to constantly be redrawn. (or maybe it's OK, but it is at least not necessary according to my requirement)

Comment: @huggie, you only need stamps if you want the path itself preserved (though it is much easier to just leave the pen down), otherwise they buy you *nothing* over just moving the turtle itself.

Comment: I have an entire maze (lines) that needs drawn using the turtle as well. So yes the path itself needs to be preserved. (Updated the original post to show the map). So I need to traverse through this map, basically.

Comment: I also want to separate the map drawing part from the traversal algorithms, which I would like my students to do find the path by recursively calling the path finding function which they had to write. Of course if the path finding at full speed is run, then the maze will be traversed immediately and the path finding process cannot be seen. And if it is being called from the timer, I don't know how I'd fit the recursive function in it.